# Overriding plugin AJAX function in your child theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have got a plugin which triggers the function `show_cart_items_html` with AJAX with in the plugin.

```
  $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_amc_get_cart', $plugin_public, 'show_cart_items_html' );
  $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_amc_get_cart', $plugin_public, 'show_cart_items_html' );



function show_cart_items_html(){

       }
```

Is this possible that `wp_ajax`  action trigger my function in the child theme instead of the plugin's function?

Comment: you can use the function [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to remove the plugin hook and then creating a new hook for AJAX https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: `remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_amc_get_cart', 'show_cart_items_html', 10 ); 
remove_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_amc_get_cart', 'show_cart_items_html', 10 ); `

Comment: I tried, but still, it is calling the same function. :(